# Method for letting customers add additional personal information (ex: default size) in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I'm a first-time Shopify developer looking for a way to let customers enter additional data about themselves in Shopify. Specifically, I'd like to add a page or modify the account info page so the customer can enter measurements. I'd then like to take that measurement information, process it, and return a recommended size for products in the shop.

Is this possible in Shopify? I am trying to figure out how to add metafields for customers to record their measurements, but I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, but would require a fair bit of customization on the merchant's part and is a bit of a hack:

When a customer is logged in [their info is available through Liquid](http://wiki.shopify.com/Customer_variable).

This allows you to reference that customer's data when rendering shop pages, e.g. a Product page.

You can assign [Metafields](http://api.shopify.com/metafield.html) to customers using the API. These are also available through Liquid.

Putting this all together, you can have a form on the shopfront asking the customer for info once they're logged in. The form submits to your server where you add the info to the Customer object as Metafields using the API. Then you have some clever Liquid on the Product page that either does the necessary calculations itself or embeds the relevant info into javascript to be processed client-side.

Comment: David, thanks for replying. I briefly conferred with the folks at sinelabs, who developed the Metafields app, and decided to record this information using tags instead. I'm going to use the contact form functionality, coupled with your suggestion to grab the logged-in customer's data using Liquid, to email the merchant the sizing information. At the same time, I'm going to try to tag the customer based on this sizing data.